# Why is there Permission denied in .conf files in Linux Kali Operating system?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Why is there Permission denied in .conf files in Linux Kali Operating system? to enabled eth0 in linux kali. because no wired connected shown.
 i tried linux command as bellow /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf it shows access denied.

Comment: i see very poor research here, for example file permisions at least.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps (replace `nano` with your own text editor of choice):

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Find lines that say

```
allow hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment those out and add `auto eth0` in their place,  like so:

```
auto eth0
#allow hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Save file.

Reboot and check network.